# How to create an additional JAR for a specific folder with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project, I need to generate three separate jars

- one for the main application (default)
- one for the source code (`maven-source-plugin`)
- and one for my app documentation which reside in `target/docs`

**Question**: How can I create a jar containing only the `target/docs` folder?

Comment: What is in the docs folder ? Something generated ?

Comment: yeah it's generated and I move it to classes/static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following to your maven `pom.xml` file, `build/plugins` section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>docs</classifier>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docs</classesDirectory>
                <includes>**/*</includes>
            </configuration>
            <id>pack-docs</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Which is basically:

- Using the `maven-jar-plugin`, [`jar`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal to pack a new artefact for the project
- Adding (or [attaching](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html)) it as a classifier (`docs` suffix appended to the normal convention for project artefacts, e.g. `artifactId-version.jar`)
- Setting the `target\docs` as source of files, using the standard `${project.build.directory}` property instead of `target` (which is its value by default)

Running

```
mvn clean package
```

You would then have as part of the output

- The `jar` file normally created, e.g. `sample-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- The new `docs` file, e.g. `sample-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-docs.jar`